# Laplace transform / gaussian random variable

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, laplace-transform, monte-carlo

We have a gaussian random variable $X \sim N(0, \sigma^{2})$, with $\sigma^{2}$ unknown.

the Laplace transform given by:

$\phi(t) := \mathbb{E} [e^{tX}]$ = $e^{{\sigma}^{2} t^2/2}$

I need to make i.i.d $N$ copies of X and compute the empirical mean

$\phi_{N} (t) := \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} e^{t X_i}$ and then calculate the confidence interval, but I am clueless where to start. Which properties of the expected value, gaussian rvs can I apply here?

Comment: You may have to assume independence.  If not, you need to specify correlations.

Comment: @herbsteinberg: thank you of course they are independent, the copies must be i.i.d

Comment: Which specific variable $\phi_N(t)$? are you asking about?  are you interested in mean and variance?

Comment: yes exactly, I want to calculate the variance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mean of average  $=\phi(t)$.  To get variance you need second moment $\frac{1}{N^2}(\sum\limits_{i=1}^N (E(e^{2tX_i})+2\sum\limits_{j=1}^{i-1} E(e^{tX_(i+j)}))=\frac{\phi(2t)}{N}+\frac{N-1}{N}\phi(t)^2$

Variance then is $\frac{1}{N}(\phi(2t)-\phi(t)^2)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.